# MvvmCross Popup Window

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I would like to have a popup window.  Even though I am using MvvmCross, it will strictly run on Android.  In Windows Store, you can do the following with xaml:

```
    <Popup VerticalOffset="300" HorizontalOffset="200" x:Name="SigPopup" >
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
            Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Button x:Name="btnAccept" Content="Accept" Click="btnAccept_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtSigner" Text="Shipper" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Margin="25,3,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
                <!-- Inking area -->
                <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                    Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="2" Width="750" Height="175">
                    <Grid x:Name="inkPanel" Margin="5">
                        <!-- Inking area -->
                        <Canvas x:Name="InkCanvas" Background="White" Margin="5" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

You can use this to popup a window to collect a Signature.  There is an accept and cancel button you can wire up accordingly.  Is there any way to do this using MvvmCross?  I have watched the ViewModel demo and saw where you could draw rectangles and put data in them and it was bound, but it didn't show how to make them go away once you were done.  I had this vision of being able to popup some sort of child ViewModel with a SignatureWidget in it and collect a signature then close the popup.  Can this be done using MvvmCross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a Xamarin Component available.
Is this something that fits your need?

http://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad

Regards,
Benjamin

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin.  That is exactly what I went with.  Once I tried to do it from the view rather than the view model, it really went pretty easily.